# Use numpy.mean to list is much slower than numpy.array

Tags: numpy

I think it is obvious that apply Numpy methods directly to Python lists is slower. I thought the reason why it was slower was because Numpy method, let's say numpy.mean, would convert list into array before calculating mean. But after trying the code below, it is **NOT** the case that: *time of converting list to array + time of numpy mean of array == time of numpy mean of list*. Could anyone explain why?

```py
import numpy as np
from time import time

r = [i for i in range(1000000)]

start_list = time()
np.mean(r)
end_list = time() - start_list

start_array = time()
np.mean(np.array(r))
end_array = time() - start_array
```

> The first one : 0.060173988342285156
>
> The second one: 0.05114173889160156

Comment: In both cases, it converts to array, under the hoods or explicitly. The bottleneck is the array conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Running the code only once watching the wall clock time is not the best way to measure its speed, because the result can be randomly and unpredictably affected by other processes. You should run it several times (the more the better) and take the mean. Python has a special module for such purposes named [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html). E.g. on my machine I get the following  results:

```
from timeit import timeit

setup = """import numpy as np
r = list(range(1000000))"""
n = 100
print(timeit("np.mean(r)", setup=setup, number=n))
print(timeit("np.mean(np.array(r))", setup=setup, number=n))
```

Output:

```
4.940829735947773
4.928034849930555
```

Or using the corresponding [IPython magic](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit):

```
import numpy as np
r = list(range(1000000))
%timeit np.mean(r)
%timeit np.mean(np.array(r))
```

Output:

```
49.4 ms ± 189 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
49.5 ms ± 202 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Which means that the execution time doesn't differ significantly.

I use Windows 10, Python 3.7.3 and numpy 1.16.2.